# Proper birational morphism with nonreduced exceptional divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $\pi: Y \to X$ be a proper birational morphism.

Let $E$ be the exceptional locus, and $Z = \pi(E)$ the scheme theoretic image (so that it is closed). I want $X,Y,Z,E$ to be smooth.

Now take $\pi^{-1}(Z)$, this is supported on $E$ and so can be written $\sum a_i \cdot E_i$.

**What is an example where $a_i > 1$?**

Note this isn't the same as the pullback of the canonical bundle having nonreduced support (which we can make via blowing up the plane twice)

Bonus points for toric answers which teach us to be comfortable with toric geometry!

Comment: If you blow up the cuspidal curve $y^2-x^3=0$ at $0$, you get the affine line and the exceptional divisor is $2\cdot 0$.

Comment: @DamianRössler I would like everything to be smooth

Comment: OK but is $E$ reduced under your assumptions?

Comment: @DamianRössler Yes

Comment: This is a good question. I suggest you ask this question on MathOverflow. The difficulty is the following. Suppose for simplicity that $E$ is irreducible. If $\pi^{-1}(Z)$ is a Cartier divisor, then you have an $X$-morphism $\phi$ from $Y$ to the blow-up of $X$ at $Z$, which is birational and surjective, and finite outside a proper closed subset $S$ of the exceptional divisor of the blow-up. By Zariski's MT, this means that outside $S$, $\phi$ is an iso and this forces the multiplicity of $\pi^{-1}(Z)$ to be one. But I don't know how to reduce to the situation where $\pi^{-1}(Z)$...

Comment: ... is a Cartier divisor. It might well be that there is a counterexample, but I lack intuition about this.

Comment: @DamianRössler Cool thanks for the partial argument! This is the sort of answer I was looking for. I was assuming everything is smooth so $E$ is cartier. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Why do you want to assume that $\pi^*(Z)$ is a Cartier divisor? I agree that in your situation, it will be generically a Cartier divisor, but the difficulty is that it might not everywhere be Cartier. Eg the non reduced plane projective curve given by $(zx,z^3)$ is generically a Cartier divisor in the projective plane, but it is not a Cartier divisor.

Comment: @DamianRössler Apparently the claim is not true, I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E$ is not smooth but a union of smooth thing it must not be reduced.

Blowup $P^2$ at $p$ to get $E_1$ . Then blowup at $q \in E_1$, then at $E_1 \cap E_2$ to get $E_3$ which will have multiplicity $2$.